# Flexbox - Variable Number of Columns Problem

Tags: css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to aim for a responsive design wherein a long list of links is arranged in columns, the number of columns varying according to the width of the display device screen.  As I understand it, I must specify the height of the container to get multiple columns.  However, then the columns continue to the right off the screen.  I do not know the length of the links.  Is there any way to do this through Flexbox? It seems like such an obvious requirement.

The CSS I have so far is:

```
/* Container */
.links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100vw !important; 
    height: 90vh;    
 }

/* Links in Container */
.links a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 20px;
}
```

Edit:  this it NOT a duplicate as commented.  The problem not that the container width doesn't grow horizontally.  The problem is that it DOES grow horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: Perhaps you need to demonstrate the issue you are having so that we can see why it's not a duplicate. At the moment, there's not much you can do about it. A **fixed height** is required to force the wrapping. If there isn't one, it won't wrap and you don't get the columns you are after. You may need a JS solution here.

Comment: It would probably help if you included a code snippet that you can run, along with a visual of what's expected, like the other question did.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just using [CSS Columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/)?

You wouldn't need to specify any height and then as the screen width changes, the number of columns will adjust based on the width you specify - taking up whatever height it needs, accordingly.

Your CSS could just look like this:

```css
.links {
  columns: 5 100px; // # of columns | minimum column width
  column-gap: 40px; // space between columns
}

.links > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">link1</a>
  <a href="#">link2</a>
  <a href="#">link3</a>
  <a href="#">link4</a>
  <a href="#">link5</a>
  <a href="#">link6</a>
  <a href="#">link7</a>
  <a href="#">link8</a>
  <a href="#">link9</a>
  <a href="#">link10</a>
  <a href="#">link11</a>
  <a href="#">link12</a>
  <a href="#">link13</a>
  <a href="#">link14</a>
  <a href="#">link15</a>
  <a href="#">link16</a>
  <a href="#">link17</a>
  <a href="#">link18</a>
  <a href="#">link19</a>
  <a href="#">link20</a>
</div>
```

[Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) for columns is pretty good.

Hope this helps!